# Spacing on inline comments with yapf

Tags: python, pep8, yapf

If I have code with inline comments:

```
def my_function():
    #my comment
    return 1+1
```

Flake8 will give me this error --> E262 - inline comment should start with '# '

It wants to see a single space after the "#":

```
def my_function():
    # my comment
    return 1+1
```

Now I've been using yapf to automatically fix just this kind of thing in my code files, and it works great. But it seems to ignore this particular pep8 error. I was wondering is there some style setting I can use to configure yapf to add this space? Or do I need to find another formatter for that?

Running yapf version '0.24.0' in python 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with yapf.

The issue is tracked and discussed at

- [yapf issue 139: Block comments should have a space after # in pep8 style mode](https://github.com/google/yapf/issues/139)

See also

- [yapf issue 512: The vim plugin cannot modify python comment format](https://github.com/google/yapf/issues/512)